# how to read second to second last word from a string in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Suppose my string is "Hello;world!How;are;you;doing?". How do I read 2nd word to second last word in a loop.
I have tried the following, but ended with errors

```
set argC=0
FOR /f %%x IN ("Hello;world!How;are;you;doing?") DO (
SET /A argC+=1
)
set /a last2last=!argC!-1   
for /f "usebackq tokens=2-!argC! delims=;" %%y in ("Hello;world!How;are;you;doing?") do (
set "somestr=!somestr! %%y "
)
echo !somestr!
```

I am getting the error "!last2last! delims=;" was unexpected at this time."
Note: Number of words in the string may vary
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does your real data contain ? ~ and spaces?

Comment: the actual string I am testing against is "&&";"XMLWrirter";"class";"free";"&&"

Answer (score 0):

Based on the actual data in the comments - this works.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%x IN ("&&";"XMLWrirter";"class";"free";"&&") DO (
if defined read SET a=!a! !b!& set b=%%x
set read=1
)
echo !a:~2!
pause
```

Comment: I have to read through the string starting from word 2 to second last(don't want traverse all the words)

Comment: I misread the question.  Does this edit solve what you need to do?

Comment: it prints as a string again ? how do I print the words in separate lines?

Comment: Asking the actual question you want answered in the first place is a good idea.

Comment: In the question itself I have pointed out that, I want to append each word separately to some other string. So I want the words as separated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "all="
set "this="
for %%a in ("&&";"XMLWrirter";"class";"free";"&&") do (
   set "all=!all!;!this!"
   if "!all!" neq ";" set "this=%%a"
)
echo !all:~3!
```

The output is `"XMLWrirter";"class";"free"`, but the semicolons may be changed by spaces, if you wish, and the quotes may be deleted.

Comment: It does work!!! Thank you....Could you please explain me how does it work? Actually, my aim is to separate words and append to another string